# clean install sublime text

Tags: windows-7, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm trying to re-install Sublime Text (3), but I keep getting back the old settings. To my (limited) knowledge, I only hae to delete the user settings in C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Sublime Text 3. (I'm on Win7)  I tried that, also uninstalling Sublime, removing the AppData folder too. But I keep getting the old settings back, again and again.

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Hmm that's all you should have to do. What settings are coming back? Plugin settings? Default settings?

Comment: Actually, everything. Even when doing a clean install it goes to the same directory I used before, and opens the last project.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the folder under `%APPDATA%` per http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html